# Setting all bitwise flags to false

Tags: c#

I have a property in my class which has a number of different object types which are defined to be in the **ON** state by default. The property looks like this:

```
private static ObjectType DefaultFilter
{
  get
  {
    return ObjectType.A |
           ObjectType.B |
           ObjectType.C |
           ObjectType.D ;
  }
}
```

In my class constructor, I have a private variable called Filter which gets set to this default state. So, my private variable looks like this:

```
private ObjectType Filter { get; set; }
```

And in the constructor, it gets set like this:

```
Filter = DefaultFilter;
```

Now, I have a menu which allows the user to set the state of each of these object types (ie. is the state of each object type set to **ON** or **OFF**). So, my menu items each subscribe to a mouse down event that looks like this:

```
var item = Menu_AppendItem(menu, "Type A", null, true, Filter.HasFlag(ObjectType.A));
item.Tag = ObjectType.A;
item.MouseDown += MenuItem_MouseDown;

private void MenuItem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  var menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
  var filter = (ObjectType)menuItem.Tag;
  if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
    if (Filter.HasFlag(filter))
      Filter &= ~filter;
    else
      Filter |= filter;
  }
  else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) 
  {
    //turn all states to OFF except the selected filter
  }
}
```

So when a user left-clicks on each item, it turns the state of that filter on or off (inverts the state). However, what I'd like to do is if the user right-clicks on an item, then it sets all of the states to **OFF** except for the selected filter. However, I'm struggling with understanding how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Filter = filter;

Comment: Oh man. I feel like a complete dummy. Your answer makes total sense. Should I delete my question?

Comment: You got answered by a legend. Just bask in it.  :-)